# How to avoid page Break between two detail rows of table in BIRT

Tags: java, birt

I have eclipse version **3.4.1** for BIRT Reporting,
I need to avoid page break between two detail rows of a table.I didn't found "avoid" option in page break properties.
My table showing data in two detail rows so may Table can be break at the end not in between two detail rows.
Example:

```
                    Employee No/Employee Name
                   --------------------------
 Detail row 1           [employee_No]
 Detail row 2          [employee_Name]
```

In above, I need to avoid page break between employee_No and employee_Name

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check this discussion, it may help you -> http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/22100-avoid-page-break/

Comment: i see, but didn't help.I need to avoid page break between two detail rows of table.

Comment: @miki, Any other solution to resolve this??

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what you are asking? It sounds like you if you have a table 2 pages long, you do not want the report to break the table between two rows.  So what do you want?

Comment: @JamesJenkins , Did you get from added detail description in question

Comment: Does the whole report consist of alternating employee_No & employee_Name or is there more data that you also don't want to break up?

Comment: No there is only one table in my report with some static header and i dont want page break between these two detail rows.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution if your design criteria will allow it; is to use a table with 2 detail columns.  Place your employee number in the left column and the employee name in the right column, this way there is no row to break, everything is on the same row.

The harder way but it will allow you keep the existing format and control page breaks between employee name and number is to use a list element with a table inside it.

In this example I have a list with a table (actually two tables) in the detail line of the list.  The table(s) each return only one occurrence per primary key (in my case a ticket ID, in yours an employee ID).  You can get as fancy as you want with table (I have extra columns for spacing, and two columns of data & Two columns of labels.)

You can then avoid page breaks in your table.

I built this report a couple years ago, and have not done anything similar for a while, so all the details of making it work are not fresh in my mind, but I don't recall it being overly difficult to figure out.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite old, but with versions 2.5 and following, you can define where in your layout do you want to avoid page breaks.

To do so, select an element in your layout, go to property editor -> page break and select "avoid" in the desired position.

Keep in mind that, depending on your layout, you probably need to set "avoid" in different point, for example after "first rows" and before "second rows" of each record in the question example.